# Publish fails in multiple processor build agent since roslyn files are locked by another project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, roslyn

I get the following error when I try building my solution in a multi core build agents.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(96,5):
>   error : Copying file obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\csi.exe
>   to
>   C:\buildAgent\work\f7321f5187869991\Deploy_output\www\bin\roslyn\csi.exe
>   failed. The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\buildAgent\work\f7321f5187869991\Deploy_output\www\bin\roslyn\csi.exe'
>   because it is being used by another process.
>   [C:\buildAgent\work\f7321f5187869991\src\Feature\VersionPruner\code\Sitecore.Feature.VersionPruner.csproj]

The msbuild command I use to trigger the build is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\MSBuild.exe" ..\MySolution.sln "/target:Rebuild" /verbosity:minimal /toolsversion:15.0 /nologo /maxcpucount /p:Configuration=%1 /property:DeployOnBuild="true" /property:DeployDefaultTarget="WebPublish" /property:WebPublishMethod="FileSystem" /property:DeleteExistingFiles="false" /property:publishUrl="%cd%\_output\www" /property:_FindDependencies="false" /p:BuildSourceFolder="%cd%\..\src" /p:BuildOutputBaseFolder="%cd%\_output\configs" /property:BuildOutputWWWFolder="%cd%\_output\www"
```

The solution builds successfully when ***maxcpucount*** property is set to 1.

Comment: Do you have more that one project building to the same output?

Comment: Yes @PauloMorgado

Comment: There you have it. Try setting one project depending on the other in the solution dependencies menu.

Comment: @PauloMorgado But my projects are not dependent, I want them to be built in parallel so that I can reduce the build time.

Comment: They are dependent because they produce the same assets to the same location.

Comment: @PauloMorgado What do you mean by same assets? All those projects are independent features and they don't have references between them except for the common library references.

Comment: You're deploying to the same destination. Common (the same) assets will be deployed to there. Or you wouldn't be having this error.

Comment: Try adding the `/bl` switch to `msbuild` and using the [MSBuild log viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/) to see if you can disable deploying these components on build. Then you'll have to deploy them yourself.